# How to send values of selected check boxes as a concatenated string in a text input on-click to a action button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's assume I have an array of check boxes (not necessarily as a part of a form). In my case 2 rows with 16 check boxes per row.
Each has his unique ID, name and value.
I need An action button to send to a form a concatenated string of selected check boxes and also to another input the number of selected boxes (count of checked) This inputs are part of a form containing and other inputs.
This is my basic functionality diagram:
[diagram of1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFmHU.png)
My question for you is how to achieve this in a stable and safe manner. JS, Jquery, other methods?

Thank you,
Here is my html/Jsquery work:

```js
//Select interval with Shift

$(document).ready(function() {
  var $chkboxes = $('.chkbox');
  var lastChecked = null;

  $chkboxes.click(function(e) {
    if (!lastChecked) {
      lastChecked = this;
      return;
    }

    if (e.shiftKey) {
      var start = $chkboxes.index(this);
      var end = $chkboxes.index(lastChecked);

      $chkboxes.slice(Math.min(start, end), Math.max(start, end) + 1).prop('checked', lastChecked.checked);
    }

    lastChecked = this;
  });
});

//count checked
var form = document.getElementById('chart');
var checkBoxes = $(form).children('.chkbox');
var count = 0;

var divBoxesChecked = document.getElementById('boxesChecked');
divBoxesChecked.innerHTML = 0;

$(checkBoxes).on('change', function() {
  $.each(checkBoxes, function(i) {
    if (checkBoxes[i].checked) {
      count++;
    }
  });

  var qty = count;

  var seld = $('.chkbox:checked').map(function() {
      return this.value;
    })
    .get()
    .join(",");


  $("#transfercape").on('click', function() {
    var pid = 125;
    var price = 4;
    $('#productprice').val(price);
    $('#productID').val(pid);
    $('#elements').val(qty);
    $('#selectionprice').val(price * qty);

    $('#teeth').val(seld);

  });

  $("#transferbonturi").on('click', function() {
    var pid = 155;
    var price = 40;
    $('#productprice').val(price);
    $('#productID').val(pid);
    $('#elements').val(qty);
    $('#selectionprice').val(price * qty);

    $('#teeth').val(seld);

  });


  console.log(count);
  //console.log($('input[class=chkbox]:checked').val(","));
  divBoxesChecked.innerHTML = count + "  elemente selectate ";
  console.log(seld);

  count = 0;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="chart">
  <h1>Chart</h1>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" id="maxila18" name="maxila18" value="18">
  <label for="maxila1"> 18</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" id="maxila17" name="maxila17" value="17">
  <label for="maxila17">17</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" id="maxila16" name="maxila16" value="16">
  <label for="maxila16">16</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" id="maxila15" name="maxila15" value="15">
  <label for="maxila15"> 15</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" id="maxila14" name="maxila14" value="14">
  <label for="maxila14"> 14</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" id="maxila13" name="maxila13" value="13">
  <label for="maxila13"> 13</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" id="maxila12" name="maxila12" value="12">
  <label for="maxila12"> 12</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" id="maxila11" name="maxila11" value="11">
  <label for="maxila11"> 11</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" id="maxila21" name="maxila21" value="21">
  <label for="maxila21"> 21</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" id="maxila22" name="maxila22" value="22">
  <label for="maxila22"> 22</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" id="maxila23" name="maxila23" value="23">
  <label for="maxila23"> 23</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" id="maxila24" name="maxila24" value="24">
  <label for="maxila24"> 24</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" id="maxila25" name="maxila25" value="25">
  <label for="maxila25"> 25</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" id="maxila26" name="maxila26" value="26">
  <label for="maxila26"> 26</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" id="maxila27" name="maxila27" value="27">
  <label for="maxila27"> 27</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" id="maxila28" name="maxila28" value="28">
  <label for="maxila28"> 28</label>

  <br>

  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" id="mandible38" name="mandible38" value="38">
  <label for="mandible3"> 38</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" id="mandible37" name="mandible37" value="37">
  <label for="mandible37">37</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" id="mandible36" name="mandible36" value="36">
  <label for="mandible36">36</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" id="mandible35" name="mandible35" value="35">
  <label for="mandible35"> 35</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" id="mandible34" name="mandible34" value="34">
  <label for="mandible34"> 34</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" id="mandible33" name="mandible33" value="33">
  <label for="mandible33"> 33</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" id="mandible32" name="mandible32" value="32">
  <label for="mandible32"> 32</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" id="mandible31" name="mandible31" value="31">
  <label for="mandible31"> 31</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" id="mandible41" name="mandible41" value="41">
  <label for="mandible43"> 41</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" id="mandible42" name="mandible42" value="42">
  <label for="mandible42"> 42</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" id="mandible43" name="mandible43" value="43">
  <label for="mandible43"> 43</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" id="mandible44" name="mandible44" value="44">
  <label for="mandible44"> 44</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" id="mandible45" name="mandible45" value="45">
  <label for="mandible45"> 45</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" id="mandible46" name="mandible46" value="46">
  <label for="mandible46"> 46</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" id="mandible47" name="mandible47" value="47">
  <label for="mandible47"> 47</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chkbox" id="mandible48" name="mandible48" value="48">
  <label for="mandible48"> 48</label>

  <br>
</div>
<div>
  <h3> numar elemente selectate</h3>
  <div id="boxesChecked"> </div>

</div>
<input type="button" value="ADD CAPE" id="transfercape">!Cape CrCo(4euro) </input>
<input type="button" value="ADD Bonturi" id="transferbonturi">!Bonturi(40euro) </input>
<div id="container1">
  <form>
    <input type="text" / id="elements" placeholder="elements">
    <input type="text" / id="productID" placeholder="productID">
    <input type="text" / id="productprice" placeholder="productprice">
    <input type="text" / id="selectionprice" placeholder="selectionprice">
    <input type="text" / id="teeth" name="teeth " placeholder="teeth" value="">
  </form>
</div>
```

This solved practically main problem, still I can't figure how to replace join separator between consecutive selected boxes from comma to minus.
String returned by .map() function need to conditionally change separator for consecutively checked boxes.
Example:
Checked: 18  14 13 12    24
Now the result is: 18,**14,13,12**,24
but I need to be: 18,**14-13-12**,24
Please help!

Comment: What have you done so far? Please share a codding snippet.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In order for others to answer your question, you need to post a snippet of the code you have so far, as well as more details.  What have you tried so far?  Are you using ReactJS or a different UI library?

Comment: Without knowing if you're using any particular framework, or anything else about what you're doing, my off the wall answer is: assign them all a specific classname or data attribute and use dom selector to grab the values. I'm used to jquery and this is easy in that, it's probably easy with just plain vanilla now too.